# How To Save A Model Instance that I Just Created In Django views?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In my views.py this is supposed to save a cart item:

```
cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(owner=owner, is_ordered=False, ref_code=ref_code)

        insert = OrderItem(item_count=item_count, price=total_price, color=color, size=size, product=product,
                        cart=cart)

        insert.save()
```

But instead, it's giving me this error even though the cart was created:

> Cannot assign "(, False)": "OrderItem.cart" must be a "Cart" instance.

Comment: the error ```
Cannot assign "(<Cart: R88A68RG1F>, False)": "OrderItem.cart" must be a "Cart" instance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of `get_or_create` is a tuple `(object, bool)`. So, when you do `cart=cart`, you are actually assigning the tuple `(, False)` to `cart` (which is what the error says).

Just correct your first line as following:

```py
cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(owner=owner, is_ordered=False, ref_code=ref_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cart, cart_response = Cart.objects.get_or_create(owner=owner, is_ordered=False, ref_code=ref_code)
OrderItem.create(cart=cart, item_count=item_count, price=total_price, color=color, size=size, product=product)
```

With create you can skip the .save()